# Selenium: Taking forever to open browser

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc

It is taking forever for Selenium to open browser. Command line shows the following:

It looks like your baseUrl (http://localhost/indico) is pointing to a file, not a directory (it doesn't end with a /).  We're going to have to strip off the last part of the pathname.

Comment: please clear that warning first and then you can see the real problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a folder with name indico and then keep your html files in it.

Now give http://localhost/indico/ as base url and */main* as absolute URL which appends the base url and become http://localhost/indico/main .

Regards

Answer (score 1):

The firefox driver is much faster than the ie one. Maybe you should start off with that one and continue from there.